# Passing a dictionary of lists to the zip function in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a dictionary that groups lists in the form `list_hostname` and its size can vary depending on the number of hosts.

I would like to zip those lists together along with another list `list_timestamp`  that isn't in the dictionary like so:

`zip(list_timestamp, list_hostname1, list_hostname2, ...)`

For e.g:

```
{
  list_hostname1: [1, 6, 7],
  list_hostname2: [4, 2, 8],
  list_hostname3: [3, 5, 0]
}

list_timestamp = ['2019-12-31', '2020-05-21', '2020-06-01']
```

I want to call the zip function like so:

`zip(list_timestamp, list_hostname1, list_hostname2, list_hostname3)`

and have this result:

`(('2019-12-31', 1, 4, 3), ('2020-05-21', 6, 2, 5), ('2020-06-01', 7, 8, 0))`

But the number of lists inside my dictionary can vary so I cannot always assume I am passing 4 arguments to my zip function.

Any idea on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Its unclear to me what you're looking for.  Could you maybe add a short example showing what your desired output is, and what you are currently getting.

Comment: @XORNAND Sorry for the confusion, I added an example to my post.

Comment: And how do you define the order of items in your dict?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille items are added from a given list of hosts and their data, so the order is arbitrary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) function:

```
hostnames = {
  "list_hostname1": [1, 6, 7],
  "list_hostname2": [4, 2, 8],
  "list_hostname3": [3, 5, 0]
}

list_timestamp = ['2019-12-31', '2020-05-21', '2020-06-01']

for element in zip(list_timestamp, *hostnames.values()):
    print(element)
```

Which give the output:

```
('2019-12-31', 1, 4, 3)
('2020-05-21', 6, 2, 5)
('2020-06-01', 7, 8, 0)
```

Note that dictionaries don't enforce ordering so `list_hostname1` might not always be in the second element of the tuple, but I don't know if you need that for your use case.